# Changing time and rpm of centifuge

Tags: lab-techniques, protocol, centrifugation

Inspired by [this](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/16181/is-half-a-tablet-of-x-a-substitute-for-a-tablet-of-x-2) question, I want to ask a question about centrifugation.

Suppose a protocol says : 10 min at 2500 rpm . Can we instead centifuge for 5 min at 5000 rpm or 20 min at 1250 rpm ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it isn't that simple, because centrifugal force varies with the square of the rotor speed. Have a look at the Wikipedia page for [clearing factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clearing_factor).

Those equations are usually used to determine what you need to do if you are going to use a different rotor, but they can also be used to solve your question.

Because you are looking at a situation where the same particles are being centrifuged, the sedimentation coefficient *s* is the same in both centrifuge runs. Also all of the factors relating to the rotor properties are the same (r<sub>max</sub> etc.). So, if you have a set of conditions that work, t<sub>1</sub> and RPM<sub>1</sub>, and you want to choose new conditions t<sub>2</sub> and RPM<sub>2</sub>, you can use the equation:

RPM<sub>2</sub> = SQRT(t<sub>1</sub>/t<sub>2</sub>) x RPM<sub>1</sub>

For the example you mention t<sub>1</sub> = 10 min and RPM<sub>1</sub> = 2500 rpm. If you change the time to 5 min:

RPM<sub>2</sub> = SQRT(10/5) x 2500 = 3536 rpm

Because the centrifugal force varies with the square of the rotor speed you don't need to double the speed if you halve the time.

Comment: So what if it was RCF instead of RPM in the question, i.e.,10 min at 2500 x g? Thank you.